# Hashing own String type with C++11

Tags: c++, string, c++11, hash, range

So I am trying to compile some codebase with clang (with libc++), but I keep finding uses of internal functions from libstdc++. Does anyone know some good method using standard library or boost/etc to hash custom string? Of course I could make std::string from it, but I don't use special string to make additional copies.

```
namespace std
{

template<>
struct hash<ct::String> : public __hash_base<size_t, ct::String>
{
    size_t operator()(const ct::String& __s) const noexcept
    { 
        return std::_Hash_impl::hash(__s.begin(), __s.end() - __s.begin()); 
    }
};

template<>
struct __is_fast_hash<hash<ct::String>> : std::false_type
{ };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "standard" way to do it, since standard library doesn't expose hashing functions for strings other than `std::string`. However, if you look in `usr/include/c++/x.x.x/tr1/functional_hash.h`, you can see their string hash implementation (I've cleaned up the code a little)

```
static std::size_t hash(const char* first, std::size_t length)
{
    std::size_t result = static_cast<std::size_t>(2166136261UL);
    for (; length > 0; --length)
    {
        result ^= static_cast<std::size_t>(*first++);
        result *= static_cast<std::size_t>(16777619UL);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And for 64 bit

```
std::size_t hash(const char* first, std::size_t length)
{
    std::size_t result = static_cast<std::size_t>(14695981039346656037ULL);
    for (; length > 0; --length)
    {
        result ^= static_cast<std::size_t>(*first++);
        result *= static_cast<std::size_t>(1099511628211ULL);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It should be pretty easy to adapt this for your code.